# Как динамически изменить цвет заливки полигонов на Яндекс картах?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

```js
ymaps.ready(['polylabel.create']).then(function () {
var map = new ymaps.Map('mps', {
    center: [52.091, 23.620],
  zoom: 12,  
    controls: []
  });
var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
var options = {
    strokeColor: '#ffffff90',  
    openHintOnHover: false, 
    labelCursor: 'pointer', 
    strokeWidth: 2
  };

 let arrPol = data; //Данные с сервера 
 objectManager.add(arrPol.map(function (feature) { 
  
 let color = (feature.properties.id=='125')?'#00a200':"#777777"; 
 
 console.log(color); //Элемент с id 125 == #00а200 остальные имеют цвет #777777;
  
 feature.id = feature.properties.id;
   feature.geometry.fillRule = "evenOdd";
   feature.geometry.type = "Polygon";
    feature.options = options;
    feature.options.fillColor = color;
    feature.type = "Feature";

    console.log(feature); //у всех элементов цвет #777777 

    return feature;
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arrPol = data; //Данные с сервера 
 objectManager.add(arrPol.map(function (feature) { 
  
            
 feature.id = feature.properties.id;
   feature.geometry.fillRule = "evenOdd";
   feature.geometry.type = "Polygon";
        feature.options = {
          opacity: (feature.properties.affil!='distr')?0.6:0,
          fillColor: (feature.properties.fillColor==undefined)?'#777777':feature.properties.fillColor,
          strokeColor: '#ffffff90',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          openHintOnHover: false,
          labelPermissibleInaccuracyOfVisibility: 25,
          labelCursor: 'pointer',
          openEmptyBalloon: true,
          strokeWidth: 2
        };
        feature.type = "Feature";

    return feature;
  }));
```